# Not able to use this while loop properly

Tags: python, list

1. Trying to sum up all the negative numbers in a list using while loop.

```
given_list_02 = [9, 8, 5, 3, -1, -2, -3, -6]
  total3 = 0
i = 0
while True:
    if given_list_02[i] >= 0:
        i+= 1
    else:
        total3+= given_list_02[i]
        i+= 1
```

Comment: This needs more information, what is the problem you experiencing? Is it an error or just incorrect logic?

Comment: why are you using a `while` loop to iterate a definite-sized list? Why not a `for` loop? Seems more fitting...

Comment: That loop will never end...

Comment: If you insist on using a `while` loop it is probably better to do `while i < len(give_list_02):`

Comment: @Tomerikoo I was able to do it easily with for loop, but since I'm new to this I wanted to do the same with while loop.

Comment: @Tomerikoo That is the thing, I'm still not really sure..I thought about it like this..In order to enter a loop you need a statement which is true/correct, right? So in order to kinda activate the loop I thought of using while True:

Comment: But you also need to terminate somehow... If you think about it, the condition I offered above is enough to also "activate" the loop ;)

Comment: @janzen It shows an InderError

Comment: Think about `while` loops like this: On every iteration (including first entry) of the loop, the statement after the `while` is checked. If it is evaluated to `True` the loop will enter one more iteration. If it is `False`, the loop will terminate and not loop anymore. So since you define `i = 0`, the condition `i < len(give_list_02)` will be true for the exact number of iterations to pass through all elements of the list...

Comment: @Tomerikoo thanks a lot! But still kinda trying to figure why while True : wouldn't work ):

Comment: @janzen yep, IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That's simple, as we said before, on each iteration the statement is evaluated and if it is `True` we enter another iteration, remember? So `True` will always evaluate to....`True`!! so the loop will keep on iterating with nothing stopping it. The idea is to have something in the body of the loop to make the condition `False` at some moment (or just use the `break` statement)

Comment: Because you increment `i` inside the loop, the condition `i < len(lst)` will become `False` in one moment, which is exactly when you reach the last element and make `i` to be equal to `len(lst)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo that really makes sense! Since I'm using while True: , does it mean that the loop will never end and also the list obviously has a limited number elements, which is probably causing IndexError?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Just read your new comment, thanks a lot for sorting this out for me! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using for loop (recommended)**

In python, [for](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) loops are based on iterators. As such, we are able to iterate over the values in the list rather than using a *while True* loop that updates an index *i*. This also makes sure we don't get an index out of bound error when *i* becomes larger than the length of the list:

```
given_list_02 = [9, 8, 5, 3, -1, -2, -3, -6]

numOfNegatives = 0
for num in given_list_02:
  if num < 0:
    numOfNegatives+=num

print(numOfNegatives)
```

**Using while loop (not recommended)**

You need a terminating condition for the while loop. If we think about what *while True* does, it will infinitely increment the *i* variable. So what would happen when *i* becomes 9? At this point, *given_list_02[i]* does not exist as *given_list_02* only has 8 elements. This is why we need to stop iterating *i* once it hits 8:

```
given_list_02 = [9, 8, 5, 3, -1, -2, -3, -6]
total3 = 0
i = 0

while i < len(given_list_02):
  if given_list_02[i] >= 0:
    i+= 1
  else:
    total3+= given_list_02[i]
    i+= 1

print(total3)
```

Comment: He does not look for the number of negative values, but their sum.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop does not have a break condition, so it will run indefinitely. As you are accessing list elements, you will access an index out out range at some point.

Try something like this

```
given_list_02 = [9, 8, 5, 3, -1, -2, -3, -6]

total3 = 0
for e in given_list_02:
    if e < 0:
        total3 += e
```

Since you commented, that you want to use a `while` loop for training purposes, try this:

```
given_list_02 = [9, 8, 5, 3, -1, -2, -3, -6]

total3 = 0
i = 0
while i < len(given_list_02):
    if given_list_02[i] < 0:
        total3 += given_list_02[i]
    i += 1
```

Keep in mind though, that you really should prefer the `for` loop in this case.